# build a pivot table using google chart table

Tags: php, json, google-visualization, pivot-table

I'm trying to build a table that shows in the v axis a list of properties, in the h axis a list of months, and the table should be build by corresponding the values.

I have build my Json object using a series of queries and operations, but i finally achieve it!

Query to get the json:

```
$rows = array();
    $table = array();

    $table['cols'] = array(
        array('label' => 'Fraccao', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'Data', 'type' => 'date'),
        array('label' => 'Valor', 'type' => 'number')
    );

$query_detalhes = "SELECT * FROM TbFraccao INNER JOIN TbLocal on TbFraccao.FkLocal=TbLocal.PkLocal INNER JOIN TbEmpresa ON TbLocal.FkEmpresa=TbEmpresa.PkEmpresa";

$result_detalhe = mysqli_query($link, $query_detalhes);

// dados para grafico

$listagem = "";

while( $row_detalhe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_detalhe)){
 $id_fraccao = $row_detalhe['PkFraccao'];
 $id_nome = $row_detalhe['FraccaoNome'];
 $id_area = $row_detalhe['FraccaoArea'];
 $id_tipo = $row_detalhe['TipoNome'];
 $id_local = $row_detalhe['LocalNome'];
 $id_dono = $row_detalhe['EmpresaNome'];
 $id_morada = $row_detalhe['LocalMorada'];
 $id_cp = $row_detalhe['LocalCp'];

$id_coluna_tabel = $id_local . " - " . $id_nome;
// OBTER DATA MAIS ANTIGA
// decidir qual é a data mais velha que me interessa





$query_old_date = "SELECT MIN(ContratoFraccaoInicio) AS INICIO, MAX(ContratoFraccaoFim) AS FIM FROM TbContratoFraccao ORDER BY ContratoFraccaoInicio ASC";
$result_old_date = mysqli_query($link, $query_old_date);

while($datas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_old_date)){

    $old_date = $datas['INICIO'];
    $end_date = $datas['FIM'];


$data_inicio = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($old_date));
$data_fim = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date));


$start    = (new DateTime($data_inicio));
$end      = (new DateTime($data_fim))->modify('first day of next month');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
   $mes =  $dt->format("Y-m-d");




    $query_valor_mes = "SELECT MAX(Data) AS DATAVALOR FROM TbContratoFracaoPreco WHERE FkFraccao='$id_fraccao'  and data<='" . $mes . "'";

    $result_valor_mes = mysqli_query($link, $query_valor_mes);

    while($row_valor_mes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_valor_mes)){
        $data_valor = $row_valor_mes['DATAVALOR'];




        $query_obter_valor = " SELECT * FROM TbContratoFracaoPreco WHERE FkFraccao='$id_fraccao' and data='" . $data_valor . "'";
        $result_obter_valor = mysqli_query($link, $query_obter_valor);

        while($row_renda = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_obter_valor)){

            $rent = $row_renda['ContratoFracaoPreco'];
            $tabela_fraccao = $row_renda['$id_fraccao'];

            $date_year = date('Y', strtotime($mes));
            $date_month = date('m', strtotime($mes))-1;
            $date_day = date('d', strtotime($mes));

            $listing =  "Date(" . $date_year.", " . $date_month .", " . $date_day . ")";

//echo $id_local . ", " . $id_nome . " - ". $mes . " - ". $rent ."<br>";
                $temp = array();
  $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $id_coluna_tabel);
  $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $listing);
  $temp[] = array('v' => (float) $rent);
  $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);

$table['rows'] = $rows;

$dados_chart = json_encode($table);

        };



    };
};
};};
```

After building the Json object ($dados_chart) I define the table:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $dados_chart;?>);

  var options = {




        };


  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart'));
   table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: false, width: '100%', height: '100%'});


}
```

Now that I have a table I want to present it like a pivot table (pretty easy in excel!!)

[image]

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to do the aggregation yourself (not pretty easy like Excel) you may be interested on delegate that work to the Database Engine but not all Databases support Pivot Tables.

PostgreSQL allows the creation of pivot tables using the crosstab on the tablefunc module.

[PostgreSQL Docs - tablefunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tablefunc.html)

[Creating Pivot Tables in PostgreSQL Using Crosstab](https://www.compose.com/articles/metrics-maven-creating-pivot-tables-in-postgresql-using-crosstab/)

MariaDB (a Fork of MySQL) has a special storage engine called CONNECT that have

[MariaDB docs - Pivoting in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/pivoting-in-mariadb/)

Comment: just solve it using WebDataRocks.com  Very easy to make it run, as soon as you fetch the data properly!